# What exception type to use when a property cannot be null?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

In my application I need to throw an exception if a property of a specific class is null or empty (in case it's a string).  I'm not sure what is the best exception to use in this case.  I would hate to create a new exception and I'm not sure if ArgumentNullException is appropriate in this case.

Should I create a new exception or there's an exception I can use?

I don't mind to throw an ApplicationException.

Comment: Take in mind too properties are syntactic sugared methods.

Comment: A related interesting discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488472/best-practices-throwing-exceptions-from-properties

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The [MSDN guidelines for standard exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx) states:

> **Do use value for the name of the implicit value parameter of property
>   setters.**
>
> The following code example shows a
>   property that throws an exception if
>   the caller passes a null argument.
>
> ```
> public IPAddress Address
> {
>     get
>     {
>         return address;
>     }
>     set
>     {
>         if(value == null)
>         {
>             throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
>         }
>         address = value;
>     }
> }
> ```

Additionally, the [MSDN guidelines for property design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) say:

> **Avoid throwing exceptions from
>   property getters.**
>
> Property getters should be simple
>   operations without any preconditions.
>   If a getter might throw an exception,
>   consider redesigning the property to
>   be a method. This recommendation does
>   not apply to indexers. Indexers can
>   throw exceptions because of invalid
>   arguments.
>
> It is valid and acceptable to throw
>   exceptions from a property setter.

So throw `ArgumentNullException` in the setter on `null`, and `ArgumentException` on the empty string, and do nothing in the getter. Since the setter throws and only you have access to the backing field, it's easy to make sure it won't contain an invalid value. Having the getter throw is then pointless. This might however be a good spot to use [`Debug.Assert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.assert.aspx).

If you really can't provide an appropriate default, then I suppose you have three options:

1. Just return whatever is in the property and document this behaviour as part of the usage contract. Let the caller deal with it. You might also demand a valid value in the constructor. This might be completely inappropriate for your application though.
2. Replace the property by methods: A setter method that throws when passed an invalid value, and a getter method that throws `InvalidOperationException` when the property was never assigned a valid value.
3. Throw `InvalidOperationException` from the getter, as you could consider 'property has never been assigned' an invalid state. While you shouldn't normally throw from getters, I suppose this might be a good reason to make an exception.

If you choose options 2 or 3, you should also include a TryGet- method that returns a `bool` which indicates if the property has been set to a valid value, and if so returns that value in an `out` parameter. Otherwise you force callers to be prepared to handle an `InvalidOperationException`, unless they have previously set the property themselves and thus know it won't throw. Compare `int.Parse` versus `int.TryParse`.

I'd suggest using option 2 with the TryGet method. It doesn't violate any guidelines and imposes minimal requirements on the calling code.

---

**About the other suggestions**
`ApplicationException` is way too general. `ArgumentException` is a bit too general for `null`, but fine otherwise. [MSDN docs again](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229021.aspx):

> **Do throw the most specific (the most derived) exception that is
>   appropriate. For example, if a method
>   receives a null (Nothing in Visual
>   Basic) argument, it should throw
>   System.ArgumentNullException instead
>   of its base type
>   System.ArgumentException.**

In fact you shouldn't use `ApplicationException` at all ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx)):

> **Do derive custom exceptions from the T:System.Exception class rather than the T:System.ApplicationException class.**
>
> It was originally thought that custom exceptions should derive from the ApplicationException class; however, this has not been found to add significant value. For more information, see Best Practices for Handling Exceptions.

`InvalidOperationException` is intended not for when the arguments to a method or property are invalid, but for when the *operation* as a whole is invalid ([docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229007.aspx)). It should not be thrown from the setter:

> **Do throw a System.InvalidOperationException exception if in an inappropriate state. System.InvalidOperationException should be thrown if a property set or a method call is not appropriate given the object's current state. For example, writing to a System.IO.FileStream that has been opened for reading should throw a System.InvalidOperationException exception.**

Incidentally, `InvalidOperationException` is for when the operation is invalid *for the object's current state.* If the operation is always invalid for the entire class, you should use [`NotSupportedException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.notsupportedexception.aspx).

Comment: @Joren, @Vadim indicates that he needs a default instructor and doesn't have a reasonable default for this field, so just monitoring the setter won't be enough for his scenario.

Comment: I agree with all that's said here. I just want to add about `ApplicationException` that's a nice one to use if you use it for 1 sweeping purpose like any business software state exceptions. It's not that the system *can't* do that, it's that it won't. It would be terrible if you threw `ApplicationException` for everything, but i'd rather just use AE than inherit from it. Inheriting to just rename something is wasted effort.

Answer (score 7):

I would throw an [`InvalidOperationException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidoperationexception.aspx).  MSDN says it "is thrown when a method call is invalid for the object's current state."

Comment: I don't think that's appropriate for this scenario.   InvalidOperationException should only be used when the object being called is invalid.  In this case the object being called is 100% valid, it's the argument to the method that is invalid.

Comment: You would throw `InvalidOperationException` if the object were in such a state that it would be invalid to use the property setter at all. That is, the *operation* itself is invalid. The MSDN docs give the example of "writing to a `System.IO.FileStream` that has been opened for reading".

Comment: I suppose we don't know the exact scenario of what's being called.  I am working under the assumption that we're calling a method of a class, and trying to use a property of that class within the method.  In that case, the object is invalid for the method that is being called (since the property needs to be set before the method can be called).

It looks like @JaredPar is considering the scenario where a property on an argument is not initialized.  In that case, his suggestion of `ArgumentException` makes the most sense.

Comment: I should add that my previous comment was purely considering the property setter. The property not being assigned to a valid value is indeed an example of invalid state. I don't think you should throw that exception from a property getter though ... there are other options.

Comment: If the state of the encapsulating object becomes invalid/non-functional because the property you are setting is invalid then I think InvalidOperationException is completely acceptable. However in such a scenario I guess that the property should be injected via the constructor as the encapsulating object depends on that property in order to fulfill it's single responsibility.

Comment: I second the answer! I have an object that has a search-method and there is a property that says search _binary_ or by _brute force_. Binary is not supported yet (because buggy). So I want to throw an exception when the property is set to _binary_ when the search-method is called. Vadim didn't say anything about setters.

Answer (score 4):

If the problem is that a member of an argument, and not the argument itself, is null then I think the best choice is the more generic `ArgumentException`.  `ArgumentNullException` does not work here because the argument is in fact not null.  Instead you need the more generic "something is wrong with your argument" exception type.

A detailed message for the constructor would be very appropriate here

Comment: What do you mean "a detail message for the constructor"?  I must have a default constructor.

Comment: @Vadim a detailed reason about why the argument exception is being thrown.  For example "Property Blah of parameter foo must be non-null"

Comment: @Vadim, he's referring to the exception's constuctor, not your object's constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not an argument, if you're referencing a property of a class.  So, you shouldn't use ArgumentException or ArgumentNullException.

NullReferenceException would happen if you just leave things alone, so I assume that's not what you're looking for.

So, using ApplicationExeption or InvalidOperationException would probably be your best bet, making sure to give a meaningful string to describe the error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are classes in the .NET Framework that throw ArgumentException from a property's setter.  I can't remember where exactly but I do remember coming across it.  You could argue that it might not be "proper" but regardless the framework has set the precedent.

Answer (score 2):

It is quite appropriate to throw ArgumentNullException if anyone tries to *assign* null.

A property should never throw on a read operation.

Comment: Where do you get the idea that a property should never throw on a read operation?  It certainly can happen easily enough.

Comment: @John I don't think his point was that it can't but merely that it shouldn't.

Comment: @John Fisher: Cwalina, Krzystof and Brad Abrams: "Framework Design Guidelines. Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for Reusable .Net Libraries", Addison-Wesley, 2006. p. 121 - among other sources.

Comment: Ah.  I certainly understand "avoid throwing exceptions from property getters", but that is quite different from "should never ...".

Answer (score 2):

If it can't be null or empty, have your setter not allow null or empty values, or throw an ArgumentException if that is the case.

Also, require that the property be set in the constructor.

This way you force a valid value, rather than coming back later and saying that that you can't determine account balance as the account isn't set.

But, I would agree with bduke's response.

Comment: I must have default constructor.

Comment: You can't put some valid default value I take it in the constructor?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't play a guessing game.  I have no idea what value should be set at run-time.

Comment: Then InvalidOperationException would be your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

Does the constructor set it to a non-null value?  If so I would just throw `ArgumentNullException` from the setter.

Answer (score 1):

There is a precedent for stretching the interpretation of ArgumentNullException to meaning "string argument is null or empty": System.Windows.Clipboard.SetText will throw an ArgumentNullException in this case.

So I wouldn't see anything wrong with using this rather than the more general ArgumentException in your property setter, provided you document it.

Answer (score 0):

Just throw whatever as long as the error message is helpful to a developer. This class of exception should never happen outside of development, anyway.