# Which/when exception to throw if property is null?

Tags: c#, exception

I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
    public Foo()
        : this(new List<Bar>())
    {
    }

    public Foo(IEnumerable<Bar> bars)
    {
        Bars = bars;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Bar> Bars { get; set; }

    public Bar GetSingleBar(Data data)
    {
        // this method returns a single Bar from the Bars property above
        // this method returns the Bar which matches the data parameter
        // this method should not return null
        // this method throws a NoBarsFoundException if
        //   (a) Bars is empty or
        //   (b) no bar in Bars matches the data
    }
}
```

What should I do if `Bars` is `null`? Should I throw an exception in the setter for `Bars` or should I throw an exception in `GetSingleBar`? (The method `GetSingleBar` is the only method which uses the `Bars` property.)

Should I throw an `ArgumentException`, `ArgumentNullException`, `InvalidOperationException`, or `NoBarsFoundException`?

Comment: also you can't new up an interface.

Comment: "*The method GetSingleBar is the only method which uses the Bars property*"... for *now*!

Answer (score 5):

Probably `System.ArgumentNullException`:

> The exception that is thrown when a null reference (`Nothing` in Visual Basic) is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid argument.

```
throw new ArgumentNullException("bars");
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say when `Bars` is `null` and it should never be `null`, then you should throw an `InvalidOperationException`, since the operation `GetSingleBar` is invalid in the object's current state, and `Bars` is a property of your class.

`ArgumentNullException`, as the name says, should be thrown only when an argument is `null`.

I would consider making `Bars` `readonly` though (if possible).

Comment: If you throw an `ArgumentNullException` when `Bars == null`, you can get a CA2208 compile warning https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2208-instantiate-argument-exceptions-correctly?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a good reason for not using a property setter, but instead a method, based on an answer from this question:

[Best practices: throwing exceptions from properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488472/best-practices-throwing-exceptions-from-properties)

This is because the property will become potentially unsafe in the form of the exception.

in lieu of bothering with that, `ArgumentNullException` is the standard when the supplied argument is null (for methods at least).

If you then try to use `Bars` before it is set or something, then I would throw an `InvalidOperationException` to signify that the object isn't in a valid state to cater for the action.

Answer (score 0):

I would throw a NoBarsFoundException in the method GetSingleBar.  This way you could have another method which allows GetSingleBar to be null.

If you always want to prevent Bars from being Null, perhaps you should set it in the constructor and make it private?

Answer (score 0):

If an empty collection causes an object to be inconsistent, I would throw in the setter.

You never know what other new methods are going to use `Bars` in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You should throw the error when setting the value because that  is where the "error" is occuring.

Also the ArgumentNullException is the correct error message.

The one issue that I have is that you should have a set method and a read-only property because most programmers do not expect an exception to be thrown. It is completely acceptable though - [Properties and Exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488472/best-practices-throwing-exceptions-from-properties)