# How to handle an invalid value in a setter?

Tags: c#

I always hear people who say setters and getters should be fast and [not throw exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1488488/1925272).

Now, if it is true, how should I handle an invalid value passed to a setter, if not throwing an exception?

Comment: "should be fast and not throw exceptions" never heard of it. I always use exception, if I want to validate the setter.

Comment: I think there is no crime to throwing exception in setter.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be based on a false premise, with no supporting links/docs.

Comment: The whole point of a property is that it does *more* than simply setting a value (well, and adds a better opportunity for encapsulation). Of course it's fine to throw an exception - but yes, properties should be fast, especially for reading.

Comment: If you aren't going to check/validate the value, why not just use a field?

Comment: I've heard that properties shouldn't hide expensive actions, but general validation or exceptions are fine. Alternatively, a completely different pattern could be used via methods with a return type of validation issues (if any). IMO validation failures are not exceptional so shouldn't be exceptions.

Comment: You are correct what you've heard.  Microsoft best practises stipulate not to throw exceptions in Setters.  Can't seem to find the documentation on this at the moment.

Comment: Edited my question. Please review it.

Comment: From your own reference "For setters they indicate that exceptions are an appropriate and acceptable error handling strategy."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx)

> AVOID throwing exceptions from property getters.
>
> Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any
>   preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably
>   be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to
>   indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the
>   arguments.

Having said that, to me, it is absolutely fine to throw exception from `setter` and normally `getters` should never throw exception.

Consider a property as attribute or characteristic of the object. So when ever you are taking value of that attribute, you should get is without any exception. You would also want that, no one should be able to set invalid value to it, so it is fine to throw exception while setting the value.

Also as a good practice,  **do preserve the previous value if a property setter throws an exception**. so that the integrity of the object is maintained. [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006(v=vs.110).aspx)

You can find some good discussion here - https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/16646/is-throwing-an-exception-from-a-property-bad-form

Comment: I assume you're pointing out that MSDN only say to avoid it in getters?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane - Yes it is for getters only, updated my answer with more details.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think it is true mainly for constructors not to throw exceptions.

For getters/setters the problem is that bindings (like WPF) might cause some problems throwing exceptions in getters/setters.

But normally there is not that much that can cause an exception, except problems during development (pre-used objects being null?).

Validation problems should not be exceptions. Exceptions are cases that should be really unusual circumstances (like an expected file that is not existing, memory shortage). Input validation and checking if a user inputted file exist should not be exceptions for example.